# Outlook does not recognize batch file variable

Tags: batch-file, outlook

I have a command below that does not recognize the batch file variable:

I set a variable called filename:

```
set filename=someName

start outlook /c ipm.note /m "<emails>&cc=<cc>&subject=<subject>&body=<body>" /a "C:\Users\roperalta\Desktop\%filename%"
```

The %filename% is giving the issue. When I replace with an actual filename, the command works just fine. Not sure what is going wrong!

Comment: Put an `echo %filename%` between those two lines and see what the result is.

Comment: I just realized it has nothing to do with the variable. It has something to do with running this command in a batch file. I tested it out on the command prompt and it allows for the command to work with an exact filename. But when I try to run it in a batch file it doesn't like it.

Comment: When I echo %filename% it just gives me the value to the assigned variable

Comment: I now think it has something to do with this     %0D%0A% that is part of my body section of the /m

Comment: Should not need to use the START command.

Comment: I found out the reason, it was because of the %0D%0A formatting keys that outlook uses. The batch file itself uses % these to output variables and so i need to escape the formatting keys that outlook uses with another % sign. At the end things like %0D%0A should look like this %%0D%%0A in a batch file.

Comment: I don't see %0D%0A% in your code anywhere.

Comment: 0D0A is just the hexadecimal value of a Windows newline

Comment: Yeah, the 0D0A was part of the body of my email. I was testing it out on the command prompt directly, but when running on a batch file it gave errors. The reason is because i needed to escape the % characters with another % character. So it really had nothing to do with what I originally posted sorry about that. Thanks everyone, we figured it out though!!!